# Getting wrong day of week for older dates (i.e. in year 1776)

Tags: python, methods

Note: This is for an intro CS course and as of now we aren't supposed to use any of the premade methods from python so...

Add the following method to your Date class:

dayOfWeek(self):

This method should return a string that indicates the day of the week (dayOfWeek) of the object (of type Date) that calls it. That is, this method returns one of the following strings: “Monday”, “Tuesday”, “Wednesday”, “Thursday”, “Friday”, “Saturday”, or “Sunday”.

Hint: How might it help to find the diff from a known date, like Tuesday, November 3, 2015? How might the mod (%) operator help?

I've successfully completed all other the necessary methods in the Date classes, but I keep getting errors for much earlier days (i.e. in the 1700s) - Also I can provide my entire class code if needed

```
days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Sunday']
        rDate = Date(11,3,2015)     #reference date - Tuesday
        i = 2                       #index for 'Tuesday'

        if self.diff(rDate) % 7 == 0:
            i = 2
        elif self.diff(rDate) % 7 == 1:
            i = 3
        elif self.diff(rDate) % 7 == 2:
            i = 4
        elif self.diff(rDate) % 7 == 3:
            i = 5
        elif self.diff(rDate) % 7 == 4:
            i = 6
        elif self.diff(rDate) % 7 == 5:
            i = 0
        else:
            i = 1
        return days[i]
```

These were the test cases provided to us that I was getting issues for:

```
>>> date = Date(6, 21, 1788)
>>> date.dayOfWeek()
'Saturday' 
>>> # I keep getting 'Sunday'

>>> date = Date(7,4,1776)
>>> date.dayOfWeek()
'Thursday'
>>> # I keep getting 'Tuesday'
```

Comment: You need to count backwards, right? `i = (2 - diff()) % 7`

Comment: Note also that you have to skip 11 days if you go before `Thursday, 14 September 1752` when the Gregorian calendar was adopted in Britain and its colonies

Comment: when you say skip 11 days what exactly do you mean?

Comment: They basically skipped past 11 days to make the new calendar match...

Comment: so then how would I account for that in my code? like which way would I need to shift the days of the week? would I add 11 days to the difference?

Comment: also, that doesn't really help me with the dates that were previously giving me issues as the years were 1776 and 1778

Comment: The `2-diff` instead of `2+diff` should fix the bug you're talking about. Talking about the Julian calendar is more a "be aware your code won't work" than something it's likely worth fixing ... timekeeping is *hard*, especially since other countries switched on different dates.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a full [mcve] (emphasis on complete), because the bug is probably in how you calculate diff. Also, it might be worth narrowing down the date by comparing your functions to the built-in functions, to help you debug (e.g. if the difference shows up in late Feb., it's probably leap year related)

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I actually figured out what was wrong... in my days string, I wrote Sunday twice instead of Saturday.